# Can we install Deja-dup on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation

How can I install Deja-dup on a 16.04 Ubuntu machine?

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu, usually it will come pre-installed. To clarify this, open up your dash and search for either "backup" or "deja".

However to install this, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install deja-dup
```

Answer (score 1):

While it is a Gnome application, you can install it on any Ubuntu flavor using

```
sudo apt-get install deja-dup
```

It should work the same no matter what desktop environment you use. I use it in my barebones openbox setup.